# List all the .csv files from a directory and its subdirectories uisng PHP

Tags: php, csv, scandir

I have a directory where a .csv file get uploaded. the structure is like this

```
MainFolder
  -User1Foder
       --User1File1.csv 
       --User1File2.csv
  -User2Folder
       --User2File1.csv
       --User2File2.csv
```

I am looking for a php function which can list all the .csv files in MainFolder.

```
listAllcsv(MainFolder);
```

output

```
User1File1.csv
User1File2.csv
User2File1.csv
User2File2.csv
```

Code Tried

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);

    unset($ffs[array_search('.', $ffs, true)]);
    unset($ffs[array_search('..', $ffs, true)]);

    // prevent empty ordered elements
    if (count($ffs) < 1)
        return;

    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        echo '<li>'.$ff;
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}
```

But its listing all the subfolder as well, i am looking for only files not the sub folder.

Thank You in Advance

Comment: i dont understand the docs. please help how to write the function that list all the csv files if a pass a directoty name to it. for my case i will pass the mainfolder

Comment: You already know how to check whether the given path is a file or a directory, so where is the problem in making the echo output of the path dependent on that as well then …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take a look at [`Iterators`](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php)

This example using [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) will do the job in a neat way.

```
function listFolders($dir) {
    $directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
    $directory->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        $directory,
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
    );

    $list = [];
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (
            $file->isDir() == false &&
            $file->getExtension() === 'csv'
        ) {
            $list[] = $file->getBasename();
        }
    }

    return $list;
}
```